# Add Key and Value to a multidimesnsion array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following multidimenson array

```
array (
  'count' => 386,
  'report' => 
  array (
    'uuid' => '183a3956-9425-43da-845c-2839c30a951b',
    'name' => 'OnlyScrumFND',
    'Have' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'uuid' => '00ad6013-4109-4940-a711-4f8fb5389e8c',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'uuid' => 'd651a86d-beac-498a-85a0-75ce62f28f4e',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I would like to add some info to the Array in a sublevel

```
foreach ($OUTPUT AS &$have['report']['Have']) {
    $have['name'] = "something";
}
```

But it is not woking, Any hint? thanks rob

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: array is not chaning - expected something like 

    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'uuid' => '00ad6013-4109-4940-a711-4f8fb5389e8c',
  'name' => 'something'
      ),

Comment: Recommend reading the [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) manual reference. You can have `foreach($arr as $value)` or `foreach($arr as $key => $value)`, and you can iterate `&$value` with reference. However you can't use `$value['foo']['bar']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. you can try with following solution.

```
foreach ($OUTPUT['report']['Have'] as &$item) {
    $item['name'] = "something";
}
```

I am using `&` operator here to modify the original array element in foreach loop instead of copied one.

Find the implementation below .

[you can check here](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yxba3pex)